# Spring app in Docker container runs on one host, fails on another

Tags: java, spring, docker, tomcat

I have a Spring web application packed in a Docker container, together with Tomcat. The app runs on several hosts, but does not start up on one particular host with this error message (split in 3 lines for easier reading):

```
19-Apr-2018 07:23:12.728 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/cglib/asm/util/TraceClassVisitor
```

The versions of Docker are identical between the hosts.

What can be the reason for this different behavior?

I assume that some run-time dependency is missing on the "bad" host. How can I find it?

Comment: Check does classpath of hosts contains  asm.jar. Often problems with cglib in case of missing this lib/

Comment: The application runs in Tomcat, so AFAIK CLASSPATH is not relevant.